# Returning empty list to QImage

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

While browsing through some Qt code, I came across a function that is defined with a return type of  `QImage`, but it's return value is an empty string `{}`. What does it mean? Couldn't figure it out from the searching I did.

Example:

```
QImage ExampleRenderer::addImage(QuickMapGL *mapItem, const QString &iconId)
{
    if (mapItem == nullptr) {
        return {};
    }
    const QImage image = iconProvider->requestImage(iconId, nullptr, QSize());
    if(image.isNull()){
        return {};
    }
    //
    ...
}
```

Comment: It means returning a default constrcuted `QImage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern C++ requires the compiler to deduce the (still static compile time) type without you needing to type it out. `return` is one of these cases, it's same as `QImage{}`, which is same as older style `QImage()`, meaning default constructed QImage value.

[Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133688/is-c11-uniform-initialization-a-replacement-for-the-old-style-syntax) is some discussion on this `{}` initialization, called *Uniform Initialization*, and why it was added to C++.